# Profiler to see time spent in methods

Tags: java, profiling

Hello I have a java application running on a Jboss server. I want to profile the application. The specific details that I am interested in is the time spent in executing the methods.

Is there any third party profiler for java/j2ee applications that will allow me to look into the time distribution for methods?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about JProfiler? In the CPU tab, you can see time spent in methods.

Answer (score 1):

It's no big deal rolling out your own implementation of an AOP advice which will measure time spent in method execution. Take a look at [Chapter 15. Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) Support](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/jboss4guide/r4/html/aop.chapt.html)

A [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366354/do-method-profiling-basic-execution-time-with-spring-aop/1366428#1366428) implemented with Spring may be used for inspiration.

Comment: Can I do APO if I am not building my app in Spring?

Comment: Yes of course. jBoss offers AOP functionalities out of the box.

Comment: Also, I think If I use AOP I will have to set point cuts for all the methods. I want all methods [both from class libraries and my custom methods in my custome classes] to be observed.