# Wrap a spring aspects with another aspect

Tags: spring, annotations, aop, wrapper, aspectj

I've declared two aspects as `foo` & `bar` over a function `runFunc` and I want to capture time taken to run the function `runcFunc` & `Bar` in `Foo`, but it is capturing the time only for `runFunc`. `Bar` is running independently.

I want that If I put two annotation over a function, the 1st annotation should wrap the 2nd annotation and the 2nd one should wrap the function `runfunc`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Hi Pankaj. You asked me to answer this, but I have to make an assumption that the reason you want to do this is to find performance problems in non-trivial code. If that's not your objective, I'm not much help. If that is your objective, I think a far more effective method is not measuring (like this code) but [*stackshots*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out aspect can wrap other aspects just as easily as they can wrap a function.

Following code works.

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Foo {}


@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Bar {}


@Aspect
@Component
public class A {

    @Around("@annotation( foo )")
    public void func1(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, Foo foo) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("foo start");
        pjp.proceed();
        System.out.println("foo end");
    }
}


@Aspect
@Component
public class B {

    @Around("@annotation( bar )")
    public void func2(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, Bar bar) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("bar start");
        pjp.proceed();
        System.out.println("bar end");
    }
}
```

The below code:

```
@Foo
@Bar
public void runFunc(){
    System.out.println("Inside Run.runFunc");
}
```

outputs the following:

```
foo start
bar start
Inside Run.runFunc
bar end
foo end
```